# delete specific edges in R

Tags: r, igraph

I'm new to programming in R and not very good so now I've got a question about my progect. I spend a lot of time in searching a specific code about "delete.edges". I want to delete specific edges from my graph, those with weight 0. I have make a txt in which i have 3 columns. the first and the second are the vertices kai the third is the weight. I wrote 0 in order to define no connection, 1,2,3 etc for connection. My graph is weighted. the plot gave me all of the posible edges including those with weight=0 and now i have to delete them and make a new plot.

Comment: I use igraph igraph, Matrix and lattice.

Comment: when you make the edgelist, just don't include the rows with weight =0 when you make the graph?

Comment: Show some code; make a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). It will be easer to help you that way.

Comment: the txt named "inn.txt" has the above form: 

node1  node2    applications
Greece  Australia    0
Greece  Austria    1
Greece  Belgium    0
Greece  Canada    2 
Greece  Denmark    0
Greece  Estonia    3

the code i have uses is:

library(igraph)
t1<- read.table("inn.txt", header = TRUE)
flogE<- graph.data.frame(t1, dir=TRUE, vertices = NULL)
flogE


i tried the above code but it didn't help

innov <- delete.edges(flogE, which(E(flogE)$weight != 0)-1)
plot(innov)

Comment: If the column header of t1 is `applications`, you may need to change weight to that

Comment: @jalapic    "applications" is the meaning of the edge. zero means no applications with the other country, etc.. you mean that i have change the scale of numbers? for example to start from "1" if there is no connection between two countries?

Answer (score 5):

I made a random graph and then randomly assigned weight of 0,1,2,3.  If you want to delete edges do in the following way:

```
library(igraph)
g<-erdos.renyi.game(100,p=.5)
E(g)$weight <- sample(0:3, length(E(g)),T)

delete.edges(g, which(E(g)$weight==0))
```